# Why my image slider not working on other pages in a subfolder using masterpage

Tags: c#

Hi been creating a web application using VS 2010 using C#.the problem i am having is that i have added image slider on the master page. but when i run the application it does not show the slider on the pages which are in a subfolder but shows the image slider in a file which is in the root.

for the image slider i have used jquery

this is how i have coded the images on masterpage

```
<div id="slide-holder">
<div id="slide-runner">
<a href=""><img id="slide-img-1" src="~/Styles/images/nature-photo1.png" class="slide" alt="" /></a>
    <a href=""><img id="slide-img-2" src="~/Styles/images/nature-photo1.png" class="slide" alt="" /></a>
    <a href=""><img id="slide-img-3" src="~/Styles/images/nature-photo2.png" class="slide" alt="" /></a>
    <a href=""><img id="slide-img-4" src="~/Styles/images/nature-photo3.png" class="slide" alt="" /></a>
    <a href=""><img id="slide-img-5" src="~/Styles/images/nature-photo4.png" class="slide" alt="" /></a>
    <a href=""><img id="slide-img-6" src="~/Styles/images/nature-photo4.png" class="slide" alt="" /></a>
    <a href=""><img id="slide-img-7" src="~/Styles/images/nature-photo6.png" class="slide" alt="" /></a> 
    <div id="slide-controls">
     <p id="slide-client" class="text"><strong>post: </strong><span></span></p>
     <p id="slide-desc" class="text"></p>
     <p id="slide-nav"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

it not showing up on the pages located in subfolders but working with pages located in the root

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that all of the src and urls are being resolved successfully. For this, use the `ResolveUrl()` function to successfully resolve all of your images regardless of the location. Also, if you are using Css, you have to make sure the images inside the css are being resolved correctly:
Example:

```
<a href=""><img id="slide-img-2" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Styles/images/nature-photo1.png") %>' class="slide" alt="" /></a>
```

Good luck!

Comment: used this for other images they seem to work with the subfolders but not with the image slider          <asp:image ID="Image2" runat="server" AlternateText="Image text"  ImageUrl="~/Styles/images/img10.jpg"/>